# Bind Grid width to ParentGrid.Width - ParentGridBorder.BorderThickness

Tags: c#, wpf

I just started with WPF, so please bear with me on any simple mistakes.

As the title states, I want to bind a Grid's width to what is essentially the InnerWidth of its ParentGrid.  So for a code example (very stripped down):

```
<Grid Name="ParentGrid" Width="300">
    <Border Name="ParentGridBorder Thickness="2" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=ParentGrid}" />
    <Grid Name="ChildGrid" Width="{**? ParentWidth - ParentBorderThickness ?**}">
        ....
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, WPF, and C# code-behind (I assume a pretty standard setup).  Any help is much appreciated.

Addendum: This was a poor and misguided approach due to my newbishness towards WPF.  The selected answer pointed out the sizing issues I was trying to create workarounds for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you ignore the Grid.Border idea and instead add a margin to the second Grid. Unless you require the border for any other reason, this is the way to go.

```
<Grid Name="ParentGrid" Width="300">
    <Grid Name="ChildGrid" Margin="10">
    ....
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Objects inside grids naturally fit their parent's size unless explicitly stated otherwise.

[image: Note the child grid maintains its size]

Note the child grid maintains its size

Comment: Beyond the need for a border, if I remove width and just have a margin, my ChildGrid only has the width of its contents rather than width of ParentGrid.  This is the reason I figured I needed to bind ChildGrid's width in the first place.

Comment: What content are you using? If you had a label inside the child grid, the child grid would still be the same size without a label...

Comment: ChildGrid has a Border and smaller Grid as children.  As a test, I removed all contents and removed the Width on ChildGrid.  ChildGrid then shrunk to a 0 width.  Did I hose a setting somewhere (maybe on Window?) to break this expected relationship?  [Also, thanks for the help. Much appreciated]

Comment: It is possible to disable the fit to parent property, try looking through the XAML and see if it has managed to slip in somewhere. I've shown a screenshot of how the window behaves. [My pleasure]

Comment: Well that's frustrating.  I'm seeing nothing to indicate disabling the property and I have very little layout-logic outside of what you're displaying.

Comment: Would you like to paste the XAML and I'll take a look?

Comment: Great scott... it was the HorizontalAlignment="Left" that was causing the behavior.  Wow. Ok, I'll attempt the borderless approach but the reason I was desiring a border is because I have WindowStyle="None" and need a frame of sorts around the window.  Thanks, again, for the help.